# Adding pages to existing pdf file

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF document with over 300 pages. I need to add 15 pages in between - after page 180. How can I do it?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You could use [pdftk](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pdftk) from the commandline:

`pdftk A=bigpdf.pdf B=insert.pdf cat A1-180 B A181-end output output.pdf`

Or if you want a GUI you could use [PDFsam](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pdfsam) (PDF split and merge), [PDFjam](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pdfjam) or [jPDFTweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/). (PDF Shuffler has already been mentioned.)

Comment: It was from 191 page that I had to add other pages. Using the following command                                          pdftk A=251.pdf B=542.pdf A1-191 B A191-end output output.pdf gave me this error                                        A1-191 not found as file or resource.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   A1-191
B not found as file or resource.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   B
A191-end not found as file or resource.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   A191-end
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.

Comment: you missed the "cat".

Comment: Oh yeah... sorry to trouble you...

Comment: How can one insert blank pages on PDFsam?

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio, A simple way to insert a blank page, regardless of what PDFsam does, is print a blank libreoffice document page using the "print to file" option.  Now you have a blank page you can add in.

Answer (score 24):

## [PDF-Shuffler](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pdfshuffler) [image: install pdfshuffler]

PDF Shuffler is an ideal application for this. It allows you to import several PDF files and rearrange the pages. You can also delete the pages you don't wish to keep in the output PDF.

[image]

Comment: Just compared [**PdfShuffler**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/) 0.6.0, [**PDF Mod**](http://live.gnome.org/PdfMod) 0.9.1 and [**PDF Split and Merge**](http://www.pdfsam.org) basic Ver. 1.1.4 (pdfsam). **PdfShuffler** is basic but simple, my favorite. **PDF Mod** and  **PdfShuffler** look similar (same icons, same presentation). **PDF Mod** is better integrated in Gnome Shell. **PDF Split and Merge** (pdfsam) looks more complex. Hope this comment helps... Cheers ;-)

Comment: PdfShuffler installs a program called PDF Arranger.

Comment: Please update this solution. pdfarranger is the new name for pdfshuffler.

Answer (score 4):

[PdfMod](http://live.gnome.org/PdfMod) works well if you prefer to use a GUI. Install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfmod
```

Comment: PDFMod appears to be extremely buggy - deleting and inserting pages causes duplicates to appear and so forth.

Comment: Yep core dumping for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try this GUI tool: [uPdf](https://launchpad.net/updf) (maintained by [atareao.es team](http://www.atareao.es/tag/updf/))

You can add blank pages, or pages from other documents or insert images, or text.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/updf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install updf
```

Answer (score 0):

Although my answer is not so smart but it will work, let's call your pdf document to be file.pdf:

1. Go to Libre office writer and use `ctrl + enter` for as many blank pages as you want. Save it on the desktop.
2. Use online doc to pdf convertor. (call it B.pdf)
3. open file.pdf and type `ctrl + p`. Following window will pop up:

[image]

In the pages field fill the pages that you want to separate. Also click on the file button to save your first 180 pages (call it part A.pdf). Save this as a separate pdf. Similarly save pages from 181 - 300 (call it part C.pdf)

4. Use online pdf merger to merge A.pdf, B.pdf, C.pdf.

Note: Although it may be little bit tedious but it doesn't involve any package at all. Using available tools you can get the desired pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Using pdfjam:

```sh
# This generates "{}{}{}...{}" and saves it into a variable called PAGES
PAGES=$(for x in {1..15}; do printf '{}'; done)
pdfjam --outfile output.pdf input.pdf "-180,$PAGES,181-"
```

In pdfjam, `{}` inside range specifications is interpreted as a blank page.